# Is weak stationary of bivariate series equivalent to weak stationary of every element of it?

Tags: time-series, covariance, stationarity

If X1t and X2t are both weak-stationary time series, can I always get Xt is weak stationary bivariate series?
If Xt is weak stationary, can we always get X1t and X2t stationary?

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between $\ell$ which appears in the matrix elements and $j$??

Comment: sorry, there must be some errors. In my opinion, l=j

Comment: Hint: the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix could make a difference between the bivariate case and two univariate cases.

Comment: Many thanks, I may have understood your idea. If I can find two stationary time series which have covariance changing with time t, my question can be solved. But emmm, I face a big problem that I cann't find and prove that. Can you give me more advice? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A *vector* random process is said to be a wide-sense stationary process (also called a *weakly* stationary process) if the mean vector has constant value (that is, $E[\mathbf X(t)]$ equals the same vector for all $t$) and the covariance matrix of $\mathbf X(t)$ and $\mathbf X(t-i)$ depends only on $i$ and does not depend on the value of $t$ at all. Now, the $(j,k)$-th term of the covariance matrix is $\operatorname{cov}(X_j(t), X_k(t-i))$ and this depends only on $i$ and not on $t$ at all. In particular, $\operatorname{cov}(X_j(t), X_j(t-i))$ is a function of $i$ alone (and the mean of $X_j(t))$ is a constant, that is, does not depend on $t$) and so $\{X_j(t)\}$ is individually a wide-sense stationary process. By a similar argument, so is $\{X_k(t)\}$  individually a wide-sense stationary process. In short, if a vector random process is wide-sense stationary, the individual processes comprising it are individually wide-sense stationary, and any two individual processes are jointly wide-sense stationary.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you that we can get individual processes are individually wide-sense stationary from the wide-sense stationary vector. But I think the correlation between individual wide-sense stationary processes may change with time t. I really want to find an example to support my idea, but it is difficult for me. So can you construct two individual wide-sense stationary time series that have correlation changing with t. Or can you strictly prove that my idea is false: two individual wide-sense stationary time series always have correlation which doesn't depend on t ?